# Reactjs background processing

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, redux

Couple of questions:

I have list of components on the client app which has some near real time info e.g. status, which I want to display.

I have server app, which can pull the status info from a third party REST endpoint.

My question is, should I cycle through all the components in the client app and request the server app for the status?

Or should I have a server worker thread, which pulls the status info and publishes on the websocket, which the client can then update the state of the component.

Or is there background thread which I can run on the client app, which will update the status and the state. How will this conflict with the dispatch/queuing of events from user interactions.

I think I might be asking some of the architectural questions and the answers might be "it depends" ambiguous, but anyone who has done this before and any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks, Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

It depends :) But it's safe to go with server-side approach since with client-side you would have to deal with CORS and cross-domain ajax calls in general. Most of the 3rd party API do not allow to make arbitrary AJAX calls from other domains. Those that do allow that usually have API quota which is again easier to manage since you can keep your keys secret on the server and throttle and cache requests.

Server side approach requires more effort though. So it's a prototype and 3rd party API allows cross-domain requests – go for it, it's easier, for production app, consider doing this on the server.

For client-side approach if 3rd party API doesn't offer subscriptions, yes you would have to poll, but you don't have to cycle through components. You can abstract this polling in one, root component and then just pass props down.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am consistently hearing server side processing :) my client wasn't directly going to talk to third party API's.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the answer is "it depends".

Basically, you have two options:

1. Poll the server for the current status.

I believe you do not have to cycle through all the components and query their status. You could just have an API that provides the server the timestamp when you last queried the status, and the server will respond with just the information that has changed since the last query.

This is simple and will work fine if the updates are not huge, and you can afford to be a little late.

2. You could have a dedicated websocket connection with the server

In this case, the server will push any new updates to your front-end whenever any new update is available. This is a little cumbersome to implement, but is the right approach if the updates are near *real-time*.

To answer your question about having a background-thread on the front-end: no, you cannot have background-threads on the front-end. Javascript doesn't work that way. What you do have are callbacks. Whenever the server pushes you any new information, a callback, that you define, will be called and you can do whatever UI changes you need from here.

Comment: I like the idea of time stamping the conversation. For the callbacks, how does the server push the new info

Comment: Depends on what you are using on the back-end, you will need to research the implementation based on what your are using. On the front-end you need to use websocket to connect to the backend. Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: Another solution would be to use a push-notification service, and send a push notification from the back-end to the front-end whenever new information is available. The front-end will then call the API to fetch new data. There are many free services for that. This is also good: https://pusher.com

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, should I cycle through all the components in the client app and request the server app for the status?

No, this sounds very inefficient to me.

However, if you decide to poll from the client, it should be done only from a single component that is parent to all children that need the information. The parent then passes its state to the children and they update on each poll.

> Or should I have a server worker thread, which pulls the status info and publishes on the websocket, which the client can then update the state of the component.

Absolutely. Let this socket be in your top-level application component which holds the real-time info in its state and passes down to its children. Whenever information gets published to the socket, update the top-level application state with the new real-time info and all children will rerender displaying the most current information.

Comment: thanks, I will go with the server side but I might have to use redis to cache on the server side the component list per socket connection.